# Cannot read property 'query' of undefined error: mysql and node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, android-studio

I'm trying to send information from android to mysql database through express server (using node js)
however there seems to be a problem in the code, it keeps showing error, but I just can't find what's wrong.
[image]

I think there's problem with connection.query statement.
Actually this is not my code, but it's the source code of my teacher. I checked everything in the android twice, but there's nothing wrong. There's gotta be something wrong here :(
[image]

This is what it is keep saying. Please help :( Stock for few days...

Comment: We can't easily read your screen captures.  Please take a few minutes and include your Node.js code as _text_, directly in your question.

Comment: a `;` after `from` in you SQL is incorrect - remove the `;`

Comment: @danblack oh i dont know when it got there but it still doesn’t work :(

Comment: check err first before accessing connection?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the getConnection() method, the callback function passed to it should check for errors first. The reason you're running into the "cannot get property of undefined" error is most likely because the connection object is never returned and therefore undefined, probably because getConnection() encounters an error.

Try adding an error check condition and log the error to see why getConnection() fails:

```
mysql_connection_info.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

  // check for errors in getting the connection
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  // carry on with the actual query if there are no errors
})
```

Comment: Thanks I done as you told me to! and it gives an error as following:
ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL cl.
I think this has to do with caching_sha2_password earlier?
I had this authentication error with heidisql about :
Failure connecting Heidi 9.5 to MySQL 8.0 due to missing plugin: caching_sha2_password .
So I've done to add something in the heidisql folder (don't really remember what it was)

Comment: Yep. It looks like the mysql client you're using doesn't support the default authentication method used in MySQL 8.0. I would suggest using a different client that does support the cached_sha2_password auth method like this one: https://insidemysql.com/introducing-connector-node-js-for-mysql-8-0/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing`mysql_connection_info.connect()`
place it just after creating the connection pool.